# Why am I getting a "wrong" mean from cumprod / cumsum of log-normal returns?

Tags: python, numpy, mean, cumsum

I'm trying to generate a [Geometric Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) "price" time series, i.e., based on log-normal returns. The goal:

- The time series should start with a price value of 1.0,
- should have a length of `n`,
- and the final/last price should have an expectation value of 1.0.

My understanding of the [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) that it has a mean of `exp(mu + sigma^2 / 2)`. So in order obtain a mean of 1.0 one has to use `mu = -sigma^2 / 2`.

My Python implementation looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np

def gen_prices(n: int, start_price: float = 1.0, sigma: float = 1.0) -> np.ndarray:
    mu = -(sigma**2) / 2
    log_returns = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=n - 1)
    prices = np.cumprod(
        np.concatenate([np.array([start_price]), np.exp(log_returns)]),
    )
    return prices
```

Let's check the mean of the final price by repeatedly generating time series, and collecting their final price values:

```py
num_iter = 100000
num_prices = 100

final_prices = [gen_prices(n=num_prices)[-1] for _ in range(num_iter)]

print(np.mean(final_prices))
```

To my surprise this returns something like `2.363741046091954e-08` far off from `1.0`. I'm wondering:

- Is there a fundamental / theoretical flaw in the approach, i.e., is `mu = -sigma^2 / 2` the wrong formula to use?
- Or is this an issue with numerical stability?

Since the result is off by many orders of magnitudes, it looked like more than "just a numerical" issue, but the formula seems to make sense on first glance.

Any ideas what is the issue here, and how to fix it?

---

For the record, I also tried an implementation based on `np.cumsum` instead of `np.cumprod`, but it seems to behave the same:

```py
def gen_prices(n: int, start_price: float = 1.0, sigma: float = 1.0) -> np.ndarray:
    mu = -(sigma**2) / 2
    log_returns = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=n - 1)
    prices = np.exp(
        np.cumsum(
            np.concatenate([np.array([np.log(start_price)]), log_returns]),
        )
    )
    return prices
```

Comment: what do you mean _"and the final/last price should have an expectation value of 1.0.
"_ ?

Comment: you are multiplying all the values. there is no way you expect that to be close to 1.  Your understanding of mean is quite distorted. Use the `np.mean` function to obtain the mean ie `np.exp(np.random.normal(size=int(1e6), loc = -0.5)).mean()` should be equal to `1` since i have taken `sigma` to be `1` and thus `loc = -1/2`

Comment: @darrenlefcoe: What I meant is that if I create say 1 million instances of such a time series, and take the last value of each, they should have an expectation value of 1. That's what the `np.mean(final_prices)` is checking. Put another way, I'd like the price time series to neither drift up or down systematically -- it starts with 1, and the expectation value of the last price should still be 1. Of course individual time series instances can have a last value vastly different from 1 -- just under taking the expectation value.

Comment: @Onyambu: I'm multiplying the values because I'd like to generate a [Geometric Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion#Simulating_sample_paths) with a specific expectation value. The implementation seems to be in line with the example on Wikipedia, which more or less also uses the  `np.cumprod(np.exp(np.random.normal(...)))` pattern, no?

Comment: But the multiplied values have no relation to the mean of the distribution. The mean of the distribution is simply the mean of the generated values. Perharps you are not to compare to 1. because what you are comparing to 1 is mean of products and not the mean of the generated values. I am not familiar with GBM but to my knowledge, consider obtaining the distribution of your GBM, and then you could obtain its mean

Comment: Sidenote. Looking at the wikipedia page you shared, It seems that the GBM is just the Log-normal distribution.  GBM might be a process that uses the LN distribution for the variable it models. So if you are interested in the mean of your process, then the mean of the LN should suffice

Comment: `it has a mean of exp(mu + sigma^2 / 2)` Note that the geometric mean and the arithmetic mean are different. e.g. If you have 1 billion, and 1 billionth, the geometric mean of that is 1, but the arithmetic mean is half a billion.

Comment: I'm able to get a closer answer by using the expected geometric mean suggested here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385249/is-geometric-mean-the-same-as-the-first-moment-of-the-lognormal-distribution By setting `mu = -(sigma**2) / (2 * n)`, the geometric mean of the output of this function is more reliably around 1. It's still usually an underestimate - not sure why.